# могут ли быть два дефиса

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать врач-психиатр-нарколог. Я считаю, что так (2 приложения, значит, 2 дефиса). Правильно ли я думаю или после врач не надо дефис? Но ведь врач -психиатр пишется через дефис? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: врач психиатр-нарколог, и для этого не надо сложных объяснений.

Дело в том, что существительное и приложение могут меняться местами в зависимости от ситуации, можно считать, что "психиатр-нарколог" - это определяемое существительное, а врач - приложение в препозиции, тогда для него дефиса не надо. Так что всё в ваших руках.

Пример: http://московский-доктор.рф/врач-психиатр-нарколог

Answer (score 3):

***Психиатра-нарколога*** (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/70650/%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80 ) я бы сочетал со словом ***врач*** с помощью тире:

***врач -- психиатр-нарколог.***

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80 :

> **§ 154.** В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
>
> ...**2.** В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей в свою
>   очередь является сочетанием с приложением и содержит дефис, напр.:
>   *рассказ о студенте-медике — альпинисте; встреча с приятелем — шахматистом-любителем; у **соседа — писателя-фантаста**.* Ср.
>   *студент-альпинист, **сосед-писатель**.*

=======================

А здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

такое написание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал: врач-психиатр, нарколог - как уточнение специализации, добавленное к характеристике общей подготовки, квалификации врача (врач-психиатр). С двумя дефисами составные части такого сочетания воспринимаются равнозначно-однородными, в то время как каждое последующее понятие здесь сужает предыдущее. В устойчивых названиях специальности врача возможен и такой вариант написания:

Врач стоматолог-протезист.